# Use a background image/texture on the physical text?

Tags: css, background, background-image

I've seen it done in SVGs: the text fill is an image rather than a color; and I've been wondering if such a thing would be possible using CSS3.

I've looked around the web, and have so far only found workarounds that are basically overlaying an image over text (see [this](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/08/09/Add-grunge-effect-to-text-using-simple-CSS.aspx), which isn't a viable option for me). Apart from actually having a background image for text, is it possible to have a background gradient?

Comment: Not really. Fonts/text can only be rendered with the single color via CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3 adds the [background-clip](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/) property. You can actually do this using [`-webkit-background-clip: text`](http://www.webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/) but the `text` value is proprietary and currently **only implemented in Webkit** based browsers (Safari and Chrome).

```
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  background: url('someimage.png');
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

A few articles that use `-webkit-background-clip: text;`:

- [Gradient Text](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/)
- [Animated background clip text](http://trentwalton.com/2010/03/24/css3-background-clip-text/)
- [Fun with -webkit-background-clip and @font-face](http://www.cssreset.com/2010/css-tutorials/fun-with-webkit-background-clip-and-font-face/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're saying, no. You can only set text to a solid color, even with the magical wonders of CSS3.